# Cant capture packets on open wifi Network and only getting Wifi Beacons?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, tcpdump, aircrack-ng

I set up an open WPA2 network and I'm trying to capture traffic on it, so I putted interface on monitor mode and first tried to capture using airodump using this command

```
sudo airodump-ng -o pcap --essid "TEST" -w output  -i wlp2s0mon
```

but I get this error:

```
Invalid output format: IVS and PCAP format cannot be used together.
```

removing `-o pcap` and the output file is `.ivs` while the network is `wpa2` network. So I decided to use `tcpdump` as

```
sudo tcpdump -i wlp2s0mon -w out ether host 59:7F:66:2A:13:68 --immediate-mode
```

but all I get is beacon frames and Qos Null functions but cant see the traffic I generate so why is this and why aircrack doesn't save data as pcap even I specify so.

Comment: Super User's format requires each Question post to really only have one question. Consider editing this question to only address the "Why am I getting this IVS/PCAP error from airocrack-ng". Your "Why am I unable to capture real data packets" question has been asked and answered on here many times. You should be able to find plenty of existing Answers for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `airocrack-ng`, the `-i` option isn't used to specify the interface, in fact it doesn't take an argument at all. It's simply a switch that means "only capture Initialization Vectors (IVs)". Capturing only IVs is useful for some encryption-cracking tasks. IVs are just part of a packet, not a packet type, so there's no good way to represent them in the `.pcap` file format, which is why `airocrack-ng` dumps them out to a ".ivs" file instead.

To specify the interface for `airocrack-ng` to capture on, you just pass it as a command-line argument at the end of the command line. It's not an option or an argument for an option.

```
sudo airodump-ng -o pcap --essid "TEST" -w somefilename.pcap wlp2s0mon
```